# Mapbox GL JS and GeoJson Files

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Currently, I am creating GeoJson files using QGIS and render them in Mapbox GL JS. I create 10 GeoJson files for each map. I am wondering what is the best practice to render the files in Mapbox GL JS. Is loading the GeoJson files in Mapbox GL JS is good enough?
Should I use some tile server or convert the files to mvt?

Comment: Using static GeoJSON is usually fine for small GeoJSON files, that won't take too long to download. As a rough rule of thumb if the GeoJSON file is <5MB compressed it should be okay. You should also optimise your GeoJSON file to contain minimal coordinate precision and feature attributes.